# How do you classify number classes in non integer bases?

Tags: number-theory

What happens if you use a non-integer base like say, base 1.5? Would 1.5 be an integer in that base, since it would look like 10?
Of course, how do write in a base like this? I start left and go the right. Why? Because, for example, in base 2, how can the number four be written?
100, 20, 12, and 4 are all perfectly valid in my notebook since all four mean the same: 1*four+0*two+0*one, 2*two+0*one, 1*two+2*one, and 4*one are all equal to four. Thus, when writing, start from left to write, unless you do base 1. That one is a bit weird.
But the question is: should we still classify numbers in non-integer bases the same way we classify them in whole numbered ones?

Comment: In base $2$, the base $10$ number $4$ would be written as $100$.  The digits "$2,4$" don't appear in base $2$.

Comment: You can read about non-integer bases [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation)

Comment: "Because, for example, in base 2, how can the number four be written? 100, 20, 12, and 4 are all perfectly valid in my notebook"  That's like saying in base 10, $100$ can be written as $100, T0, 9T$ and $H$ where $T$ is the digit for $10$ and $H$ is the digit for $100$.

Comment: The digit expansion of a number is unique if we fix the base ( as long as we use an integer base greater than $1$ ). "$4$" is not valid in base $2$. Number systems based on non-integer bases are weird. I see no reason why we should use them at all . Number systems based on negative bases are also weird, base $1$ makes no sense becuase we do not have a unique representation, since every power of $1$ is $1$. Moreover, what should be the digits ?

Comment: "I see no reason why we should use them at all . "  Because we can. It's purely theoretical."base 1 makes no sense becuase we do not have a unique representation, since every power of 1 is 1".  So $11111 = 1^4 + 1^3+1^2+1^1 + 1^0 = 5_{10}$.  Not a problem.  "Moreover, what should be the digits"  $1$. But there is not $0$ and therefore it can only represent natural numbers via counting tallying only  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system

Comment: ""I see no reason why we should use them at all . ""  lulu's cited article gives some very good reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers are what they are, independent of any base that we happen to choose to represent them.

By convention, representing an integer  $n$ in base $b$ means writing 
$$
n = a_0 + a_1b + a_2 b^2 + \cdots + a_kb^k
$$
where the "digits" $a_i$ are integers between $0$ and $b-1$. If you recognize that the digits are themselves just integers, which you need not think of as represented in any particular way, you can do lots of interesting elementary mathematics.

If you relax the convention that the digits must be less than the base you have a lot more flexibility - expansions are not unique = but that is sometimes useful. You can add a list of numbers written in base $10$ column by column without "carrying" and save all the carrying for the end.

With the relaxed convention your several ways to write $4$ in base $2$ are all correct.

In *The Lord of the Rings* 
 Bilbo Baggins celebrates his eleventy-first birthday. That's the base $10$ number with  $11$ in the tens column and  $1$ in the ones column.

The integers in base $1.5$ are the expansions in which the digit in the $i$th column are even when $i$ is odd.

For much more along these lines do spend time with exploding dots: 
https://www.explodingdots.org/

Answer (score 1):

> "Would 1.5 be an integer in that base, since it would look like 10?"

Conventionally that is not what the word "integer" means.

Values are values no matter how they are written.  $7_{10}$ is an integer.  So are $\sqrt{49}$ and $\frac {42}{6}$ and $VII$.  But $1.5_{10}$ is not.  Neither is $1\frac 12$, $\frac 32$ or $10_{1.5}$.

You are correct that $10_{1.5}$ is a finite decimal representation with only non-negative powers of its base.  But if there is a term for "finite decimal representation with only non-negative powers of its base" I do not know what it is.  But it is not "integer".

I think what you are getting at is that for integer bases, $b \ge 2$ the  "finite decimal representation with only non-negative powers of its base" *are precisely* the natural numbers.  All natural numbers are "finite decimal representation with only non-negative powers of its base".  And all  "finite decimal representation with only non-negative powers of its base" are natural numbers.[1]

This is *not* the case with non-integer bases (for obvious reasons).

---

> "100, 20, 12, and 4 are all perfectly valid in my notebook "

They aren't because in base $2$ the digits $2$ and $4$ are not allowed.  With only the digits $0, 1$ allowed $100$ is the only finite way to write the number $4_{10}$.  However using infinite representation $4_{10} = 11.1111111......_{2}$.  (Because $4 = 2 + 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 14 + \frac 18 + \frac 1{16} + ........$.  This is the same as saying in base $10$ that $4 = 3.9999999999.........$.)

---

**In integer bases ($b \ge 2$) all finite representations are unique.  That is not necessarily true for non-digit basis.**

I'm not sure whether it is for base $1.5$ or other rational bases.  I think it is true but I'm too lazy to prove it and I don't want to eat my words if I am wrong.

But for the golden ration $\phi = \frac {1+\sqrt 5}2$ we have $\phi + 1 = \phi^2$.  ($\phi^2 = \frac {(1+\sqrt 5)^2}4 = \frac {1 + 2\sqrt 5 + 5}4 = \frac {6+2\sqrt 5}4 = \frac {3+\sqrt 5}4 = \frac {1+\sqrt 5}2 +1 = \phi +1$)

so $\phi + 1= \phi^1 + \phi^0 =11_{\phi}$ and $\phi^2=\phi^2 + 0*\phi + 0*\phi^0  = 100_{\phi}$ so $11_{\phi} = 100_{\phi}$.

So it isn't true for base $\phi$.

=======

[1] This raises the question what *is* the definition of "integer"?  Well, The integers form the smallest group and the smallest ring containing the natural numbers. ANd the natural numbers are .... well see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Formal_definitions

However in base $10$ or in any other positive integer base at least $2$ these are *presicely* the positive and negative value that are "finite decimal representation with only non-negative powers of its base" we often, especially in elementary and high school, think of this as a definition rather than a consequence.  But it is not the definition.  An actual definition will either require a lot of circular boot strapping ("An integer is a whole number that doesn't have sub-unit parts.  What's a sub-unit part?  That's something that can't be written as a whole number.") or far too abstract axioms for an elementary student.